# expression engine ajax call module function

Tags: jquery, ajax, module, expressionengine

I need youre help , i'm working on expression engine 2.x and use uploadify to upload files with jaquery method.

In the js code i need to provide upload url script .
And don't how to reach calling of my module function registered in db .
I tried index.php?ACT=function_name but nothings append
Thx

$.ready(function(){

```
$('.uploadify').uploadify({
    'swf'           : 'http://ee.statistic.local/index.php/themes/thrid_party/bmm_cloudupload/swf/uploadify.swf',
    'uploader'      : '**http://ee.statistic.local/index.php/index.php?ACT=108**',
    'checkExisting' : false,
    'debug'         : false,
    'cancelImage'   : 'http://ee.statistic.local/index.php/themes/thrid_party/bmm_cloudupload/uploadify-cancel.png',
    'folder'        : 'http://ee.statistic.local/index.php/tmp',
    'auto'          : false,
    'buttonText'    : 'Select Files',
    'fileTypeExts'  : '*.*',
    'queueID'       : 'upload-queue',
    'removeCompleted'   : false,
    'uploadLimit'       : 0,
    'multi'             : true,
    'transparent'       : true

  });
```

});

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert your 'uploader' method into the actions table during the module's install, which will give you the action ID to use.

http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/development/modules.html